# How to increase the height of an UICollectionViewCell and stay at the same position in the ScrollView?

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell, uicollectionviewlayout

In my application I have an `UICollectionViewController` for which I change the `UICollectionViewLayout`. The custom `UICollectionViewFlowLayout` changes nothing but the height for the cells. The problem is when setting the new `UICollectionViewFlowLayout`, the position in my `UICollectionView` changes completely, especially the further down I am. My goal is to achive that the `UICollectionViewCell` that is at the top (but not hidden by the navigation bar or even further up) stays at the top of the view after I update the `UICollectionViewLayout`.

Here is some code on how i tried to solve it:

```
class PacksCollectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewFlowLayout {

    convenience init(height: CGFloat) {
        self.init()
        itemSize = CGSize(width: 80, height: height)
        minimumInteritemSpacing = 10
        minimumLineSpacing = 10
        sectionInset.left = 10
        sectionInset.right = 10
        scrollDirection = .vertical
    }

    override func targetContentOffset(forProposedContentOffset proposedContentOffset: CGPoint) -> CGPoint {
        return collectionView!.contentOffset
    }
}

class PacksCollectionViewController: UICollectionViewController {

    var largeCells = false {

        let height:CGFloat = largeCells ? 110 : 80
        var lowestIndexPath:IndexPath? {
            return self.collectionView?.indexPathsForVisibleItems.min()
        }

        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3){
            self.collectionView?.collectionViewLayout.invalidateLayout()
            self.collectionView?.setCollectionViewLayout(PacksCollectionViewLayout(height: height), animated: true)
            if let index = lowestIndexPath{
                self.collectionView?.scrollToItem(at: index, at: .top, animated: false)
            }
        }
    }

    override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 100
    }

    override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        return collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: PacksCollectionViewCell.identifier, for: indexPath)
    }
}
```

When trying to scroll to the `UICollectionViewCell` that is listed as the lowest `IndexPath` in `collectionView?.indexPathsForVisibleItems` it moves way to far up because those cells are apparently still visible too. Any solutions on that matter?

Answer (score 0):

this is how I did it, I hope this helps and sorry if it doesn't
so on your flow layout add this code

```
  required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    commonInit()
}

override init() {
    super.init()
    commonInit()
}

func commonInit() {
    minimumLineSpacing = 10.0
}

fun yourCollectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, sizeForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGSize {
    return CGSize(width: collectionView.bounds.width, height: 230.0)
}
```

and on your main collection controller add this

```
  let layout = yourFlowLayout()



   override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

 collectionView?.collectionViewLayout = layout


 func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGSize {
    return layout.yourCollectionView(collectionView, sizeForItemAtIndexPath: indexPath)
}
```

I hope this helped :)

Comment: `yourCollectionView` has the parameter `indexPath`, but it is never used in the function. Can it be that the function is incomplete?